# Stop Macro to add headers in imported data (headers has to be added manually because the coulmn no. differs each time)

Tags: excel, vba

How do I stop my macro to insert headers manually in different sheets converted from text files and then process further with analysis.

Comment: You will need to explain your problem a lot more clearly if you need help.  Right now your question is too vague.

Comment: basically i want the same macro button having two codes to run after different click on the button

Comment: You will need to macro to be able to detect that the first step is complete, and run the second step.